# Zoom or slice a section of canvas HTML5

Tags: html, canvas, zooming, pie-chart

I working on HTML Canvas library to construct a **"PIE Chart"** Now to finish it I need the
given section of PIE Chart to Zoom or Slice once clicked on the section.

I almost done with the PIE Chart with the above exception only

Please do not recommend me to use any charting library available already

Comment: OK Don't use a library, but read the Canvas manual and API documentation carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want cannot directly be done: when you draw on the canvas, you paint pixels that instantly dry onto the canvas. If you want to "zoom in" you'll have to erase the canvas (`ctx.clearRect(...)`) and re-paint your pie chart using more pixels. This is what a *non-retained drawing mode* (or *immediate drawing mode*) graphics API like Canvas requires.

Contrast this with SVG, a *retained drawing mode* graphics system, where the commands to draw content result in elements being created that you may track events for, adjust properties on, and see the visual results updated for you.

You can "zoom in"--redraw your pie chart larger--either by changing your drawing commands (bigger `arc` radius, `lineWidth`, etc.) or by [transforming your context](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#transformations) (changing the scale and translation) and then issuing the same drawing commands again.

*There is also one non-option: if you leave the `width` and `height` attributes of the canvas unchanged but change the `CSS` to `height` and `width` properties you can 'zoom in' on your canvas without re-drawing. This is going to cause each virtual pixel on the canvas to grow on your screen, however, resulting in pixelation.*